# BottomSheet не выезжает

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

прикрутил к приложению bottomSheet, но он отказывается выезжать, по крайней мере его не видно на экране. он пишет в логи, реагирует на свайп и на программное выдвижение, но его не видно на экране.

[весь код тут](https://github.com/Nickdnepr/snp2/tree/Nickdnepr)

P.S.
извините, что не кинул код прямо сюда, у меня при копипасте не ставятся пробелы, и код не выделяется

Comment: bottomsheet'ом вообще не пахнет если честно

Comment: извиняюсь, поправил ссылку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бегло просмотрел код, вроде в порядке. На самом деле он вызывается, дело в разметке: вы вынули его из под `DrawerLayout` , хотя он должен находиться там и на самом верхнем уровне.

В случае, если я ошибся -  [предлагаю альтернативу.](https://github.com/rey5137/Material/wiki/BottomSheet)

Comment: теперь он выезжает только после того, как я открыл navigation drawer. и даже не выезжает, а резко появляется

Comment: @nick_dnepr он появляется, верно?А каким способом - настраивайте под Ваши нужды. Вопрос был в том, что его не видно на экране. Смотрите на то, как он появляется, и подстаривайте конфигурацию.